# angular: redirect to equivalent hash route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Is there some way with angular (or javascript) to catch a post to

http://mysite/route

and have it redirected to

http://mysite/#/route

without any routing stuff on the server side?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe you can achieve this by utilizing the `interceptors` component of angular's `$http` service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 1):

You could use basic JavaScript and a redirect on page load to redirect to your desired page. If you want to make it more dynamic read the url and parse it as needed in the js script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = "set this to your desired url such as /#/route";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a hacky and hardcoded way (that's why I won't accept this answers unless something better shows up)

I created a /route/index.html file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      window.location ='/#' + window.location.pathname;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, I was expecting to find a more generic solution...